# Focus border not appearing when TalkBack is enabled on Android devices

Tags: android, cordova, focus, accessibility, talkback

I am working on a Cordova Application for Android and iOS devices and I want to integrate accessibility into the application. I am having an issue with the focus border. When TalkBack is on for Android devices, the voice assistant recognizes the buttons and reads them to the users. However, there is no focus border appearing highlighting the item. On iOS devices, it works as expected and there is a focus border appears when an item receive the focus.

Does anyone have an idea of what might cause this issue? I am using Cordova with Jquery UI for development.

Comment: If you turn "Show Layout Bounds" on in Developer options, can you see the outlines of views? I would _guess_ that Cordova is providing some kind of virtual view hierarchy since you're not using the native controls, but not specifying the bounds that are associated with each "view" so the border is not drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I turned on Show Layout Bounds and there are no borders/outlines/bounds for any controls of the application! By any chance you have a solution to this?

Comment: 'fraid not, sounds like a cordova limitation so they'd have to draw too. I guess they've implemented the virtual view hierarchy and the correct callbacks but they don't draw which is the currently focused view